# Materialize tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, materialize

I'm trying to use materialize tabs in my website but it's not working at all please help me someone where have i done mistake.

```
<div class="container z-depth-4 storeLocation">
    <div class="row hr-top">
         <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
             <h4>Today's menu</h4>
         </div>
    </div>

  <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 m12 l12">

          <ul id="tabs-swipe-demo" class="tabs">
            <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test-swipe-1">Test 1</a></li>
            <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test-swipe-2">Test 2</a></li>
            <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test-swipe-3">Test 3</a></li>
          </ul>
     <div id="test-swipe-1" class="col s12 blue">Test 1</div>
     <div id="test-swipe-2" class="col s12 red">Test 2</div>
     <div id="test-swipe-3" class="col s12 green">Test 3</div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div> <!-- main container div -->
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tabs').tabs();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: i guess you missed to include jQuery

Comment: no i have included jquery in the footer section

Comment: please check https://jsfiddle.net/Gaurav_Kumar_Rana/fe5tg97x/4/ i solved your problem here.

Comment: Add jquery in the top of your app before material.js

Comment: thanks bro can you please tell me the reason also why it was not working. i have heard that it's good practice to include scripts at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Normally all library or plugins should be include at the top of the app. And app related javascripts you can include at the bottom of you HTML.

Answer (score 1):

i guess you missed to include jQuery in your app. Please refer to below jsfiddle `[https://jsfiddle.net/Gaurav_Kumar_Rana/fe5tg97x/4/][1]`

Comment: if you feel like my answer solve your problem. please accept it.